# Continuity in dense set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

*Prove that if $f$ is continuous and $f(x)=0$ for all numbers $x$ in a dense set  $A$, then $f(x)=0$, for all $x$* .

**Proof.** *Suppose that $f(x) \neq 0$, for some $x$, as $f$ is continuous then there is $\delta>0$, such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, given that a set $A$ is dense, there is $\alpha \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$, for $\alpha \in A$, then $f(\alpha)=0$, but this is  a contradiction,  since $\alpha \in A$, hence $f(x)=0$* .

I'm not sure if it's necessary to use the case in which $f(x)<0$ and $f(x)>0$ .

Other Proof:

*Given that A is a dense set, there is $x_{n}\in A$, such that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$, then $f$ is continuous $f(x_{n})\rightarrow f(x)$*, given that $x_{n} \in A$, then $f(x_{n})=0$, thus $f(x)=0$

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a bit of reasoning but mostly got the argument down. When you assume $f(x)\neq0$ for some $x$, you can pick some radius $\delta>0$ such that $f(y)\neq0$ for all $y\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$. But, there is a $y$ in this open set that also is in $A$, completing the proof.

We can actually generalize this proof as follows:

> If $X,Y$ are topological spaces, and $Y$ is $T_1$, and $f:X\to Y$ is continuous such that for some dense set $A\subseteq X$, $f\vert_A$ is constant, then $f$ is constant.

Proof: Let $f\vert_A(a)=c$ for some $c\in Y$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there exists some $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=d\neq c$. Since $Y$ is $T_1$, there exists an open set $U\subset Y$ such that $d\in U$ but $c\notin U$. By continuity, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. But, every non-empty open set in $X$ must contain an element of $A$ since $A$ is dense. But, this is a contradiction since $c\notin f(f^{-1}(U))$.

Since $\mathbb R$ is $T_1$ under the standard topology, this generalization proves your desired result.